# Restore a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I was entering information on my Google Sheet and walked away. Then when I went to entered another number in a cell an error message came up and the entire sheet disappeared.

There must be a way to find a previously saved version?

Answer (score 4):

In the menu bar, click the words to the right of "Help": they say either "Last edit was ..." or "All changes saved in Drive". This opens the revision history of the document. You can choose a recent revision and restore it.